# How to hide table class until data is returned?

Tags: javascript, html, quickbase

As indicated in the code. The user enters data into one of the 6 input boxes. Query results are returned in (example: `<td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="PROC_CODE" name="PROC_CODE">&nbsp;</td>`)

I need to have the blank `<td><tr>` hidden unless query results are returned.

The code is long but fairly simple and straight forward. Basically the user queries 1 record, 1 record displays. User queries 4 records 4 records display.

I already have the db working and pulling the results I need I just don't know how to hide the blank tables data

```
enter code here

<body style="text-align: center">
  <a name="top"></a>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
    <!-- xxxxxxx Logo -->
    <td height="50" width="150">
     <a href="http://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com"><img src="http://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/contentowners/xxxxxxx_template/js/images/xxxxxxx_50.gif" alt="xxxxxxx" width="150"
     height="50" border="0"></a>
    </td>
    <!-- xxxxxxx Search -->
    <td height="50" align="right">
     <iframe src="/provider_services/search.html" name="search" id="search" width="475" height="50" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" align="right" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <!-- Current Date -->
    <td height="28" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFF66" class="smblue">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/contentowners/xxxxxxx_template/js/date_short.js">
</script>

    </td>
    <td height="28" bgcolor="#99CC33">
     <!-- Top Navigation (optional for your site) -->
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
       <td class="topnav" id="TOPNAV">       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
    <!-- left col -->
    <td width="150" valign="top" bgcolor="#ADD1EE">
     <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
       <!-- Insert your site name here -->
       <!-- Link this text to your homepage or main index -->
       <h5 align="center" class="white"><img src="../../images/psc_logo_150x150.jpg" width="150" height="150"></h5></td>
<body onLoad="loadCommon();" style="text-align: center">
<script src="../../psc_nav_bar.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<td class="leftnav" id="LEFTNAV">
</table>
</td>


    <!--center col -->
    <td valign="top">
     <!-- begin content table -->
     <form action="" method="post" name="frmTracking" id="frmTracking" onReset="clearControls(this);">
<input type="hidden" name="recordID" value="">
<p>
     <br>  <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
  <tr align="left">
    <td align="left"> <p><U><strong>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <br></p>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
  <tr align="left">
    <td align="left">
    <input name="searchRecord" id="searchRecord" type="text"  size="8" maxlength="8">
<input name="searchRecord" id="searchRecord" type="text"  size="8" maxlength="8">
<input name="searchRecord" id="searchRecord" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8">
<input name="searchRecord" id="searchRecord" type="text"  size="8" maxlength="8">
<input name="searchRecord" id="searchRecord" type="text"  size="8" maxlength="8">
<input name="searchRecord" id="searchRecord" type="text"  size="8" maxlength="8">
</td>
  </tr>
    <td>  <div id="TRACKBUTTONS" align="center">
          <input type="button" name="btnFind" value="Find"
                                                                class="cmdBtn" onClick="return getDBRecord(this.form);"><input type="button" name="reset_form" value="Clear" onclick="this.form.reset(); history.go(0) "   >

         <!--  <input type="button" name="btnSave" value="Save" class="cmdBtn" title="Save current entry" onClick="return updateDBRecord(this.form);"> -->
        </div></td>

</table>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td colspan="5" align="center" class="th2">Procedure Code Record</td>
    </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Procedure Code </td>
      <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="PROC_CODE" name="PROC_CODE">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Medicare Advantage </td>
      <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="MEDICARE" name="MEDICARE">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
            <tr>
             <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Procedure</td>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="STATUS">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Specialty</td>
              <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" class="tLBL1l" id="xxxxxxx_ID">&nbsp;</td>

            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Precert Type

              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">
              <td width="55%" class="tLBL1l" id="SYS_APP">&nbsp;</td>
      &nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="DETAILS3">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="1%" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="5%" class="tLBL1l" id="td">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Review Type:</td>
              <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="tLBL1l" id="SUBMITTER">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="td">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Guidelines:</td>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="EMAIL">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="td4">&nbsp;</td>

           <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td colspan="5" align="center" class="th2">Procedure Code Record1</td>
    </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Procedure Code </td>
      <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="PROC_CODE1" name="PROC_CODE">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Medicare Advantage </td>
      <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="MEDICARE1" name="MEDICARE">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Procedure</td>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="STATUS1">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Specialty</td>
              <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" class="tLBL1l" id="xxxxxxx_ID1">&nbsp;</td>

            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Precert Type

              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">
              <td width="55%" class="tLBL1l" id="SYS_APP1">&nbsp;</td>
      &nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="DETAILS31">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="1%" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="5%" class="tLBL1l" id="td">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Review Type:</td>
              <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="tLBL1l" id="SUBMITTER1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="td">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Guidelines:</td>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="EMAIL1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="td4">&nbsp;</td>

    <!--3rd set -->
              <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td colspan="5" align="center" class="th2">Procedure Code Record2</td>
    </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Procedure Code </td>
      <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="PROC_CODE2" name="PROC_CODE">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Medicare Advantage </td>
      <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="MEDICARE2" name="MEDICARE">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Procedure</td>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="STATUS2">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Specialty</td>
              <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" class="tLBL1l" id="xxxxxxx_ID2">&nbsp;</td>

            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Precert Type

              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">
              <td width="55%" class="tLBL1l" id="SYS_APP2">&nbsp;</td>
      &nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="DETAILS32">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="1%" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="5%" class="tLBL1l" id="td">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Review Type:</td>
              <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="SUBMITTER2">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="td">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Guidelines:</td>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="EMAIL2">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="td4">&nbsp;</td>

              <!--4th set -->
                          <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td colspan="5" align="center" class="th2">Procedure Code Record3</td>
    </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Procedure Code </td>
      <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="PROC_CODE3" name="PROC_CODE">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Medicare Advantage </td>
      <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="MEDICARE3" name="MEDICARE">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Procedure</td>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="STATUS3">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Specialty</td>
              <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" class="tLBL1l" id="xxxxxxx_ID3">&nbsp;</td>

            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Precert Type

              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">
              <td width="55%" class="tLBL1l" id="SYS_APP3">&nbsp;</td>
      &nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="DETAILS33">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="1%" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="5%" class="tLBL1l" id="td">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Review Type:</td>
              <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="tLBL1l" id="SUBMITTER3">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="td">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Guidelines:</td>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="EMAIL3">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="td4">&nbsp;</td>

              <!--5th set -->
                          <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td colspan="5" align="center" class="th2">Procedure Code Record4</td>
    </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Procedure Code </td>
      <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="PROC_CODE4" name="PROC_CODE">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Medicare Advantage </td>
      <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="MEDICARE4" name="MEDICARE">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Procedure</td>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="STATUS4">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Specialty</td>
              <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" class="tLBL1l" id="xxxxxxx_ID4">&nbsp;</td>

            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Precert Type

              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">
              <td width="55%" class="tLBL1l" id="SYS_APP4">&nbsp;</td>
      &nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="DETAILS34">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="1%" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="5%" class="tLBL1l" id="td">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Review Type:</td>
              <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="tLBL1l" id="SUBMITTER4">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="td">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Guidelines:</td>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="EMAIL4">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="td4">&nbsp;</td>

              <!--6th set -->

                                     <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td colspan="5" align="center" class="th2">Procedure Code Record5</td>
    </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Procedure Code </td>
      <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="PROC_CODE5" name="PROC_CODE">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Medicare Advantage </td>
      <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="MEDICARE5" name="MEDICARE">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Procedure</td>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="STATUS5">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Specialty</td>
              <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" class="tLBL1l" id="xxxxxxx_ID5">&nbsp;</td>

            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Precert Type

              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">
              <td width="55%" class="tLBL1l" id="SYS_APP5">&nbsp;</td>
      &nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="DETAILS35">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="1%" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="5%" class="tLBL1l" id="td">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Review Type:</td>
              <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="tLBL1l" id="SUBMITTER5">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="td">&nbsp;</td>
            <tr>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Guidelines:</td>
              <td align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="EMAIL5">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="tLBL1l" id="td4">&nbsp;</td>
    <!-- <tr id="rowTIN">
      <td align="right" class="tdFieldHeadingsR">Change Status</td>
      <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="3" class="tdFieldHeadingsR"><!-- <input name="txtTinPin" type="text" title="TIN/PIN" value="" size="12"> -->
       <!-- <label for="txtTinPin"></label>
        <select name="txtTinPin2" size="1" id="txtTinPin">
          <option value="Open" selected>Open</option>
          <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="rowControlNumber">
      <td align="right" valign="top" class="tdFieldHeadingsR">Handler Notes</td>
      <td class="tdFieldHeadingsR">&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="3" class="tdFieldHeadingsR"><textarea name="txtControl" cols="50" rows="8" title="Handler Notes"></textarea></td>
    </tr> -->
    <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="5"> 
        <p></p>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">

      <tr>
       <td valign="top">
        &nbsp;<p align="center">
          <img src="http://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/contentowners/xxxxxxx_template/js/images/up_arrow.gif" alt="" width="12" height="13" border="0" align="middle">&nbsp;<a href="#top" class="top">top of page</a></td>

                   <!-- Right column for boxes -->
      </tr>
     </table>

                 <!-- end content table -->
    </td>
   </tr>
   <!-- end center column -->

   <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
     <hr size="1">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>

     <a href="http://www.xxxxxxx.com/">
<img src=
     "http://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/contentowners/xxxxxxx_template/js/images/logo_footer.gif" alt="xxxxxxx" width="149" height="65" border="0" align="right"></a>

<!-- begin footer -->
<p align="left" class="pubinfo" id="PUBINFO">
</body>
```

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to post questions. A deluge of code is not helpful - no one wants to read it. Just post a relevant stripped-down example.

Comment: well, that will depend on your getDBRecord() function. If you are pulling the data with ajax, you could assign a callback function to it and show the controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give table some id and call $(tableId).hide(); Optionally you may want to show the table but disable it until data is returned

Comment: Guess I should simplify. Just need to hide the rows below unless populated.Sorry,used to posting all my code to ExpertsExchange. Thanks

<tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td colspan="5" align="center" class="th2">Procedure Code Record</td>
    </tr>
     <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
      <td width="12%" align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">Procedure Code </td>
      <td width="1%" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tdFieldHeadingsR1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="55%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="tLBL1l" id="PROC_CODE" name="PROC_CODE">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>